# Constraint to randomize such a way that consecutive 2 bits are set to 1, other bits are 0 for 16-bit variable

Tags: constraints, verilog, system-verilog, unique-constraint

I need to write a constraint to randomize such a way that consecutive 2 bits are set to 1, other bits are 0 (i.e. 16'b0000_0000_0011, 16'b0000_1100_0000, etc.) for a 16-bit variable.

I tried using `$countones`.  It is working for two bits, but it is not working consecutive 2 bits.  Its display is:

```
# Value is 10000000000100 
# Value is 10000000010
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to use a random index variable which is constrained between 0 and 14, then use another constraint to set only the 2 bits of your data.

```
module tb;

class c;
    rand bit [ 3:0] idx;
    rand bit [15:0] data;
    constraint c0 {
        idx < 15;
        data == (3 << idx);
    }
endclass

initial begin
    c c;
    c = new();
    repeat (20) begin
        c.randomize();
        $displayb(c.data);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Example output:

```
0000110000000000
0000011000000000
0000110000000000
0110000000000000
0000110000000000
0000000000110000
0000000110000000
0000110000000000
0000110000000000
0000001100000000
0000000000000011
0000001100000000
0000110000000000
0001100000000000
0000110000000000
0000000110000000
0011000000000000
0000000000110000
0000000000110000
0000001100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class packet;
  rand bit[15:0] data;
  rand bit[3:0] idx;
  
  constraint c_data { data == 0; }
  
  function void post_randomize();
    data[idx] = 1'b1;
    if(idx == 15) data[0]     = 1'b1;
    else          data[idx+1] = 1'b1;
  endfunction
  
  
  
endclass

module top;
  initial repeat(5) begin 
    packet p; 
    p = new();
    p.randomize();
    $display("%b", p.data);
  end 
endmodule
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).